# I cant type a "." with keycode

Tags: keypress, gecko

I have a problem with the geckoWebBrowser1 firefox browser component. In the geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted event I want to put an email address to a textbox.

I have to do that using the keypress event as the textbox requires the user to actually type the address. The code I have do work but there is a problem with the "." (dot) in the email: "myemail@hotmail.com"

I have found out the keycodes: 46 and 8228 is a "."
1. When I pass 46, it doesn't even type the "." in the textbox
2. When I pass 8228, it DO type the "." in the textbox but the webpage says that the email doesn't seem to be valid so it cant be a valid "."

My question is how to put a valid "." like I try to do. 
Or if it is possible to inject the string itself DIRECTLY instead of using Keycodes?

```js
        private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            String emailaddress = "myemail@hotmail.com";
            var element = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login-email");
            if (element != null)
            {
                DomEventArgs ev = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.CreateEvent("KeyEvents");
                var webEvent = new Gecko.WebIDL.Event(geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, ev.DomEvent as nsISupports);
                webEvent.InitEvent("focus", true, false);
                element.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);
                var nsIEventVar = ((nsIDOMKeyEvent)ev.DomEvent);
                char[] inputChars = emailaddress.ToCharArray();
                foreach (var vchar in inputChars)
                {
                    int keyCode = 0;
                    if (vchar == '.')
                    {
                        keyCode = 46; //or 8228
                        nsIEventVar.InitKeyEvent(new nsAString("keypress"), true, false, geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, false, false, false, false, (uint)keyCode, (uint)keyCode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        keyCode = (int)(System.Windows.Forms.Keys)vchar;
                        nsIEventVar.InitKeyEvent(new nsAString("keypress"), true, false, geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, false, false, false, false, (uint)keyCode, (uint)keyCode);
                    }
                    Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMEventTarget>(element.DomObject).DispatchEvent(nsIEventVar);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: At a cursory glance, 8228 can't be `'.'`. Probably a character that *looks* like it, but not the one you'd want in an email address.

Comment: That's not JavaScript. It looks like it might be Java.

Comment: Yes 8228 seems to just only look like a '.' but strange thing is that 46 is a "." but the code wont type it out in the textbox?

Comment: 190 `event.keycode`

Comment: Anyway, why are you treating it differently then other characters?

Comment: @Mark 190 prints out a: ¾

Comment: @Federico If I treat it like the other characters it chooses the 46 which doesn't print out a "." It is really spoky why it doesn't print the "." out for 46

Comment: I looked up the keycode for "." in java just in case and it is VK_PERIOD which also has the integer 46

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricky way to solve it.

I first set an attribute value: ".com" (including the ".")
Then I start to keypress the rest of the email: "myemail@hotmail"

This did work and was then recogniced as a "."

```js
     elements.SetAttribute("value", ".com");
     String emailaddress = "myemail@hotmail";
```